# Сокращение стилей css (gulp)

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, gulp

Подскажите плагин для `gulp` который сокращает стили
Например:

```
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 300;
font-family: 'OpenSans';
line-height: 1.2;
```

Сокращенный вид

```
font: 300 16px/1.2 'OpenSans';
```

Comment: Формально эти две записи неэквивалентны. https://codepen.io/alexeyten/pen/VxWxWv

Comment: `font: italic small-caps 300 16px/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;`
Вот как должно быть записано в сокращенном виде, из вашего примера.

Comment: Не-а. Обновил пример.

Comment: Я в вашем же примере проверял! все правильно работало до ваших изменений!

Comment: А теперь не работает. Потому что вы не учитываете, что в первом варианте не упомянутые свойства наследуются, а во втором сбрасываются в `normal`. И только по CSS-у вы не можете заранее знать в каком контексте будет использован `.x2`

Comment: Я знаю что в сокращенном варианте не наследуются свойства.
Но вопрос я задал совсем о другом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен плагин **shorthand** https://github.com/vol7/shorthand.
Делает что-то такое:

```css
a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url('example.png');
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a {
  font: italic bold 14px/18px Arial;
  background: red url('example.png') no-repeat / cover;
}
```

Пример подключения

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shorthand = require('gulp-shorthand');
 
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/index.css')
        .pipe(shorthand())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```